# Will ACTF aDesigner/aiBrowser useful for manual accessibility testing

Tags: eclipse, accessibility, wcag

I am looking for tool for manually testing the web application pages for accessibility compliance. ACTF's aDesigner/aiBrowser looks very good and provides good automated testing.

In the same ACTF's browser if user wants to examine the attributes of a UI control and check the accessibility guidelines, and then find the issue, Is it possible to achieve? Here user may do Firefox's web developer like functionality on UI controls, then go for accessibility testing. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a11y toolbars that will do most of what you want for major browsers, can only post one link though.

IE:
paciellogroup.com/resources/wat
visionaustralia.org/digital-access-wat

Firefox:
firefox/addon/accessibility-evaluation-toolb/
http://wave.webaim.org/toolbar/

general tools:
wat-c.org/

Comment: sorry, posted before finished.  the ACTF browser is primarily a tool for end users to gain better control not for testing.  I'd start with webaim tools.

Comment: Hey Mike, welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for this answer! Just for future reference, if you accidentally truncate your answer / post it early, you can use the http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22183351/edit edit link to go back and fix the original post...

Comment: Thanks yochannah, I had indeed missed that toolbar.